# Error Could not create the Java virtual machine while creating Websphere 7 profile

Tags: java, websphere, windows-7-x64, websphere-7, ibm-rational

I try run PMT (Profile Management Tool) from RAD (Rational Application Development) but I got the error "Could not create the Java virtual machine" even when I started RAD as Administrator. I searched in the internet and all recomendations I saw didn't work for me. Firstly, I try open the comand line as Adminstrator and run manageprofiles. Secondly, I downloaded certain tool named run_manageprofilesInteractive but I still got the same error. Finaly, I saw some recomendation to add two variables to restrict memory size. All details are below printed from a command line running with admin privilege.

```
First tentative:
C:\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\bin>manageprofiles -create -templatePath "WebSphere
Application Server, v7.0 test environment Installation Location\profileTemplates
\default" -isDeveloperServer -profileName dev_profile_Secure -enableAdminSecurit
y true -adminUserName wasadmin -adminPassword wasadmin -cellName localhostNode01
Cell -nodeName localhostNode01
JVMJ9VM011W Unable to load j9jpi24: The specified module could not be found.
Error: could not load Mercury Interactive support. Please run the setup again.
       If the problem persists please contact Mercury's Customer support.
JVMJ9VM011W Unable to load j9jpi24: The specified module could not be found.
JVMJ9VM015W Initialization error for library jvmhook(-3): JVM_OnLoad failed
Could not create the Java virtual machine.


C:\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\bin>java -version
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -agentlib:jvmhook
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xrunjvmhook -Xbootclasspath/a:C:\PROGRA~2\HP\QUICKT~1\
bin\JAVA_S~1\classes;C:\PROGRA~2\HP\QUICKT~1\bin\JAVA_S~1\classes\jasmine.jar
java version "1.6.0_45"

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_45-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.45-b01, mixed mode)

Second Tentative:
C:\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\bin>run_manageprofilesInteractive.bat

C:\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\bin>CALL "C:\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\bin\setupCmdLi
ne.bat"
JVMJ9VM011W Unable to load j9jpi24: The specified module could not be found.
Error: could not load Mercury Interactive support. Please run the setup again.
       If the problem persists please contact Mercury's Customer support.
JVMJ9VM011W Unable to load j9jpi24: The specified module could not be found.
JVMJ9VM015W Initialization error for library jvmhook(-3): JVM_OnLoad failed
Could not create the Java virtual machine.

Lsat tentative after restarting the machine.
C:\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\bin>set _JAVA_OPTION
_JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xrunjvmhook -Xbootclasspath/a:C:\PROGRA~2\HP\QUICKT~1\bin\JAVA_S~
1\classes;C:\PROGRA~2\HP\QUICKT~1\bin\JAVA_S~1\classes\jasmine.jar
```

Comment: If you are running on Windows you should run with IBM JVM provided with WebSphere not with hotspot. So try to clear JAVA_HOME and PATH system variables from paths pointing to Oracle JVM. Then open command line, go to C:\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\bin and run manageprofiles script using correct parameters. Template path in your first try is for sure incorrect. No jvmhooks or Mercury stuff shouldnt be picked up during profile creation.

Answer (score 0):

before installation you need to check the JDK path should be directly under c:/
like this

C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_27
and be sure that jre is also in the same folder like this C:\Java\jre6

check the compatibility of JDK version with the Websphere...download and install correct version of JDK...

Also set the path environment variable(Control Panel\System and Security\System->Advance system setting->go to Advanced tab->go to environment variable) with correct JDK path like this

PATH=C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_27\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program File
s\Lenovo\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\Lenovo\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared

hope it will solve you problem...as it solved mine.

Answer (score -1):

You need to set JAVA_HOME and PATH Variables , then it will work.